# Allow class to be assigned as zero

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm writing a template function, and I want to initialize a template variable to zero. I was thinking of setting the variable equal to zero, and then let the class type define its own definition of "zero":

```
T data = 0;
```

I tried overloading the assignment operator:

```
class Example{
public:
    int data;
    Example(){}
    Example& operator=(int v){
        data = v;
        return *this;
    }
};

template <class T> T test(){
    T data = 0;
    return data;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    double v1 = test<double>();
    Example v2 = test<Example>();
    return 1;
}
```

... but the compiler gives me "error: conversion from 'int' to nonscalar type...". How can I make this work? or is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Probably you want constructor that takes `int` as a parameter.

Comment: It sounds like you should really be [value-initializing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) the variable instead of setting it to zero. (Also, `T data = 0;` tries to construct `data` from `0` instead of assigning `0` to `data`. It's confusing.)

Comment: Hmmm, okay, I didn't realize the constructor syntax worked for primitives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `T data = 0;` actually calls a constructor, not `operator=`. So in order your code to work, you need to declare a constructor accepting an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You should note make your classes assignable to `0`. You should use brace initialization:

```
template <class T> T test(){
    T data{};
    return data;
}
```

It will construct any default constructible types correctly and will zero initialize built-in types such as `double` or `int`.